# Ad hoc synch not working for reset devices

Tags: ios, restore, adhoc, udid

I dont know if anyone can help me here, our previous lead developer has left and now we need to change the Apple ID’s associated with a number of IOS devices to a more generic company ID.

His account was revoked for our developer program membership and as a result I have generated a new provisioning file and certificate in order to continue with our ad hoc testing.

All seemed fine; however the 3 devices that were associated with his account will no longer synch through iTunes.

For these I have restored them to their original settings through iTunes, renamed the device and associated it with our new generic company Apple ID.

Their UDID’s remain the same as before and .ipa’s generated work for other devices associated with different Apple ID’s. So the new certificate seems to be valid.

Could the previous account be lingering in some way?

Is the device’s UDID also associated with an Apple ID?

Is there some particular procedure I need to go through in order to truly wipe an IOS device?

Will I have to re register those devices UDID’s?

If anybody has any idea what the issue might be I'd be very grateful for some clues